# WebClient Encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, webclient

When I'm sending a request with Webclient, my request string is converted to ????

I set the Encoding, but it's not working.

This is my Code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient(){ Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 })
{
    client.Encoding = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8;
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/octet-stream";
    client.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)");
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");

    string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("admin" + ":" + "123456"));
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);
    client.Headers.Add("command:12");

    byte[] bret = client.UploadData("http://192.168.1.1", "POST",
                  System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("code=سلام;field2=value2"));

    string sret = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bret);
    MessageBox.Show(sret);
}
```

sniffing with Wireshark, the request string convert to ??? :

> POST / HTTP/1.1
>  Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU2
>  command:
>   setPersons12
>  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Host: 192.168.1.21:8080
>  Content-Length: 23
>  Expect:
>   100-continue
>  Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> code=????;field2=value2HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>  Content-Length: 10
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

try with this code , i hope be useful

```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            ....

        }
```